# UIAlertController have different DOM structure in iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, automation, uialertviewcontroller

[image]I am showing `UIAlertController` in `iOS` and same code executes for `iPhone and iPad`. So can anyone help with this. As I google but didn't find any thing to justify this. Below is the code I have used:-

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Button.Ok".localizedValue(), style: .destructive, handler: { _ in

})
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Button.Cancel".localizedValue(), style: .default, handler: { _ in
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
alert.accessibilityLabel = self.viewModel.deleteUserConfirmationAccessibilityId()
alert.addAction(okAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So the problem is this:- 
iPhone :  "Remove all saved" text come under UIAView of the DOM Structure when doing automation testing for the UIAlertController in iPhone.
iPad : "Remove all saved" text come under UIView of the DOM Structure when doing automation testing for the UIAlertController in iPad.

So why difference is coming in UIAlertController structure as iPhone iPad showing UIView and iPhone UIAView for the same code.

Comment: Your problem is not clear by the description provided. Please edit/update the question

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: can you at least make some screenshots ?

Comment: “So why difference is coming in UIAlertController structure as iPhone iPad showing UIView and iPhone UIAView for the same code.” Because an iPhone is not an iPad. If Apple wants to construct the interface differently for the different device types, they can. What’s the problem?

Comment: Automation tester have problem, apple is fine with this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add popoverpresentation controller for ipad. Please see below code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Button.Ok".localizedValue(), style: .destructive, handler: { _ in

})
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Button.Cancel".localizedValue(), style: .default, handler: { _ in
alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
alert.accessibilityLabel = 
self.viewModel.deleteUserConfirmationAccessibilityId()
alert.addAction(okAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
//self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
        // for iPAD support:
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x:self.view.bounds.width / 2.0, y:150, width:1.0, height:1.0)
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}else{
        // for iPHONE support:
        let rootViewController: UIViewController = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
        rootViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```